# Value collectAsMap is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Any, Any)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to use `collectmap()` in the following statement but getting the below error.

```
val Comic_Titles=comics_df.map(array => (array(0), array(1))).collectAsMap()
```

`error: value collectAsMap is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Any, Any)]`

Any idea how I can turn this into a map?

Answer (score 2):

`collctAsMap` is part of `PairRDDFunctions`, i.e. it is only available to `RDD` of 2-Tuples:

```
val Comic_Titles=comics_df.map(array => (array(0), array(1))).rdd.collectAsMap()
```

What you can do in Dataset API is

```
val Comic_Titles=comics_df.map(array => (array(0), array(1))).collect().toMap
```